# Handle non-ASCII characters from shell output in Windows

Tags: php, utf-8

I wrote this short code to output the ping.
But there are umlauts in my output, since i am running this command on a german windows 7 computer, these umlauts (ö,ä,ü) are always visible as `?` in the output.

So i tried to set the locale to `de_DE.UTF-8` but this did not helped either.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    $locale=    'de_DE.UTF-8';
    setlocale   (LC_ALL,    $locale);
    putenv      ('LC_ALL='.$locale);

    $result = shell_exec('ping www.google.de');

    echo $result;
?>
```

Snippet from my output:

> Ping wird ausgef�hrt f�r www.google.de [173.194.112.248] mit 32 Bytes
>   Daten:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: What data are you receiving? Maybe it's need to be decoded as UTF-8?

Comment: See my updated question pls.

Comment: Well, the problem is that your shell isn't actually returning UTF-8 encoded data. The question is what encoding *does* it return and possibly how to tell it to return something else. I don't know how to do this in Windows, but good luck.

Comment: Why would ping command via shell_exec output utf8 encoding anyway?